# How can create folder url that includes html file object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple HTML file objects and I can access them via blob URL one by one. I want to create a URL for multiple files so that I can access them via `'/'` like relative path.

For example, I have 2 files with the names `bunny.png` and `bunny.jpg`. I can create a blob URL for both of them and I can access the two of them one by one. Now I want to create a URL like `blob:urlForMultipleFiles` and I want to access the `bunny.png` via this URL `blob:urlForMultipleFiles/bunny.png` like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @UlysseBN — This isn't a debugging question.

Comment: [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) doesn't accept anything but object, thus you can';t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Blob URLs represent a single encoded resource.

There is no provision to store multiple resources in a blob and then extract different resources by using a URL suffix.

You could possibly encode multiple resources by using a blob representation of a zip file … but you'd need to extract the different resources from it using JavaScript and not URL syntax.